# how to minimize windows by active windows?

Tags: windows

How do I automatically minimise windows when another window gets active? Let's say I am using Chrome and Avaya Softphone for receiving calls.

How do I minimise Chrome tabs when Avaya gets a ring or another tab gets active?

Comment: Doable with e.g. AutoHotKey https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/114019-minimizing-all-windows-except-active-one/ + https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/41549-how-to-activate-or-fire-an-event-when-a-window-opens/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PHsU5sVj if you prefer autoit you can use this as a base

Comment: Thank you bro i will try and tell you

Answer (score 0):

An brute-force method can be written using
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
and will look something like:

```
#Persistent
DetectHiddenWindows, Off

SetTimer, CheckIfActive, 500
return

CheckIfActive:
WinGet, id, list,,, Program Manager
Loop, %id%
{
    this_ID := id%A_Index%
    if not WinActive(ahk_id %this_ID%)
        WinMinimize, ahk_id %this_ID%)
}
return
```

However, this script will need to be customized to avoid minimizing
widgets and other windows that might be hard to unminimize, so it
shouldn't be used as-is.

Comment: Thank you my brother. So i don't need to press any key that will minimize nonactive window and the active window will show ? And secondly i am sorry but can you make ahk file that works for 2.0 version of autohotkey because this only version works for me

Comment: You could use [AHK v2 Script Converter](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=25100), but there are others.

Comment: so i don't need to prees any key it will minmize nonactive window when another window gets active like avaya rings right?

Comment: Yes, as written it loops every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: okay i will mark this answer as usful but pleas i am sorry i can't convert v1 to 2 can you make me a file and give link or give me the script for v2 ?

Comment: but bro it minmize all windows i need to minmize window when another window gets active like avaya gets ring are you understandme?